# Import Photos from Iphone to Android

Tags: stock-android, photos, ios

I've been trying to access the wedding pictures I stored 5 years ago. I was an iPhone user, but now I'm using an LG K10 Android.

I know the photos were store on either iCloud Photos OR Photostream in my old iPhone. I don't know if I can import them to my Android phone. I do not have access to a PC with internet access. Can anyone help me?

Comment: 1. We know you fell distress, but please don't spam caps. 
2. To be able to help import the pictures we would need to know with certainty where are your photos stored, otherwise we would be be just making wild guesses...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get all your pictures from you iPhone to your LG is to use Google Photos. This does requires a gmail account. If you don't have one, its free to set up.

On your iPhone:

1. Download Google photos (if not installed already)
2. In the Google photos app, tap Menu (3 horizontal lines)
3. Select **Settings** then **Backup and Sync**
4. Switch it on
5. Allow permissions, if required

On your LG:

1. Download Google photos (if not installed already)
2. Repeat steps 2, 3 and 4 for iPhone
3. Your pictures should be on your LG

Hope this helps!